# Overloaded subclass function that takes an instance of the subclass as a param, how to use?

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

I am attempting to create something like this:

```
class A{
public:
  virtual void doSomething(&A); //Generic to do something with ANY two A's 
};  

class B : public A{
 public:
  void doSomething(&B); //More specific for two B's (subclass of A)
}

main(){
  A* p1 = new B();
  A* p2 = new B();

  //Should this execute B::doSomething(&B)? If not, how can I?
  p1->doSomething(*p2); 
}
```

My actual implementation is similar to this

```
 std::list<A*> items; 
...
 //items gets filled with instances of A and B here
...
 for (std::list<A*>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); it++){
  for (std::list<A*>::iterator it2 = items.begin(); it2 != items.end(); it2++){
         (*it)->doSomething(**it2);
      }
 }
```

How can I get B's function to run in favour of the base classes when the parameter is a B but I only have pointers to the base class?

Thanks, this is my first time asking a question so I hope I have structured it correctly.

Comment: This smells like a "double dispatch" type of problem...

Comment: You may also want to add "virtual" in front of void doSomething(&B);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an `A` to `doSomething()`, so the compiler is going to call `doSomething(A&)` (either `A::doSomething(A&)` itself, or a derived `doSomething(A&)` via polymorphism).  `B` is not **overriding** `doSomething(A&)`, it is **hiding** it with `doSomething(B&)` which is not related to `doSomething(A&)`.  You cannot pass an `A` to `doSomething()` and expect `doSomething(B&)` to be called.  To do what you are attempting, `B` needs to **override** `doSomething(A&)` and then use an RTTI lookup via `dynamic_cast` to check whether the input value is actually a `B` or not, eg:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void doSomething(A&);
};  

void A::doSomething(A &a)
{
    // perform code for all A objects, including
    // the A portion of descendants of A...
}
```

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void doSomething(A&);
};  

void B::doSomething(A &a)
{
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a);
    if (b)
    {
        // perform code for all B objects, including
        // the B portion of descendant of B...
    }

    // optional: call the inherited method if you want
    // to invoke the base code for all objects...
    A::doSomething(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did think about dynamic_cast but I couldn't figure out where to do the casting.

I implemented it like this and now it's working as expected, thanks again.